# C# String Interning Garbage Collection

Tags: .net, string, c#-4.0, garbage-collection

While referring to CLR via C# according to Jeff, C# interning enhance performance substantially in CLR. When the CLR initializes, **it creates an internal hash table in which the keys are strings and the values are references to String objects in the managed heap**. The public static String Intern(String str) method, Intern, takes a String, obtains a hash code for it, and checks the internal hash table for a match. Till here its perfect and the way of working too. But here is the game changer "**String objects referred to by the internal hash table can’t be freed until the AppDomain is unloaded or the process terminates.**" So every string you creates, its hash code will be maintained and freed only at the time of Appdomain Unloads so is it a bad design? or is my understanding is not clear? please explain.

Comment: How many times do you actually call `string.Intern` (or use a `ldstr` IL command)? If you aren't calling `string.Intern`, **nothing else matters** - most strings are not, and will never be, interned

Comment: In case you want to use string interning but only need it for a limited time, you can build yourself a [local intern pool](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/02/12/string-interning-effective-memory-management-with-dotmemory/#:~:text=the%20intern%20pool.-,Local%20Intern%20Pool). A typical scenario would a long running server application / service that sometimes needs to process a lot of data retrieved from a database (i.e. with same keys/captions due missing normalization or maybe even  intentional denormalization for perf reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is clear.

Your reasons for worrying are not.

If you do something like this:

```
for( int i = 0;  i < 100000;  i++ )
   String.Intern( "bla-bla-bla-bla-bla" + i );
```

then you will be creating lots of strings that will never be garbage-collected.

But if you just do

```
String.Intern( myName );
String.Intern( myApp );
String.Intern( myCompany );
```

then you will be creating just 3 strings that will never be garbage-collected.

So, if you just make sure that you use `String.intern()` in situations like the second, rather than the first, you will be fine.

Generally, as (Marc points out), you don't have to invoke String.Intern() yourself.  The compiler in collaboration with the runtime will make sure to intern everything that is worth interning, or *potentially* worth interning.

To give you an example of a situation where you may potentially want to intern strings: say, you are going to create a finite number of threads, and you want to name them, say "Thread0" through "Thread9", by appending a counter from 0 to 9 to the string "Thread".  And say, you want to maintain a `Dictionary<String,Thread>` so you can lookup threads by name.  In this case, it pays to intern these thread names.  The thread names do not already exist as constants in your program, so they are not already interned, and you will not be creating many of them, and they will remain constant throughout the runtime of your program, so they are good candidates for interning.

Comment: Minor point: they were interned *before* you called `string.Intern`; then were interned when the `ldstr` IL instruction ran - this is a guarantee of the `ldstr` operation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarcGravell of course, you are right.  I can't think of an example that would not suffer from this problem.  Even `enum` value names are pre-interned.

Comment: agreed; and to go with that : in most invented scenarios that *aren't* interned, they will be eligible for GEN-0 collection (the cheapest kind of GC; not free, but very cheap)

Comment: Thank you @MikeNakis and MarcGravell for your example and info.